# MySQL Inner cursor executes only one time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `remove_schedule_duplicate` ()
BEGIN
    BLOCK1 : BEGIN 

    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE schedule_id CHAR(36);
    DECLARE gamePk INTEGER;
    DECLARE keep_entry TINYINT(1);
    DECLARE scheduleDuplicate CURSOR FOR SELECT game_pk FROM schedule where is_active = 1 group by game_pk,home_team_id,away_team_id,venue_id having count(game_pk) > 1 limit 2;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN scheduleDuplicate;

    get_schedule_duplicate: LOOP

    FETCH scheduleDuplicate INTO gamePk;

    IF finished = 1 THEN
        LEAVE get_schedule_duplicate;
            END IF;

            **BLOCK2 : BEGIN 

            DECLARE block_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE blockDuplicate CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM schedule where game_pk = gamePk and is_active = 1;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET block_finished = 1;

            OPEN blockDuplicate;

            block_schedule_duplicate: LOOP

            FETCH blockDuplicate INTO schedule_id;

            IF block_finished = 1 THEN
                LEAVE block_schedule_duplicate;
                        END IF;

                        IF keep_entry = 0 THEN
                            UPDATE schedule set is_active = 0 where id = schedule_id;
                        END IF;

                    END LOOP block_schedule_duplicate;

                    CLOSE blockDuplicate;

            END BLOCK2;**

        END LOOP get_schedule_duplicate;

        CLOSE scheduleDuplicate;

END BLOCK1;

END 

$$
```

The problem is Innerloop first time execute well after that block_finished always be 1 so. always it quits the inner block.

How to resolve this issue. What i do ? Some one help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Still, I am not able to find the reason. So I have changed the stored procedure with the single cursor and achieve the effect of the above stored procedure with some conditions.

Comment: Is like touch the nose around the head.

DECLARE scheduleDuplicate CURSOR FOR SELECT game_pk,id FROM schedule where game_pk in (SELECT game_pk FROM schedule where is_active = 1 group by game_pk,home_team_id,away_team_id,venue_id having count(game_pk) > 1) and is_active = 1 order by game_pk;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

Comment: Publish the structure of the tables as well as some test data and it will be easier help you.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `game_id` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
  `game_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_team_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `away_team_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `venue_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `game_pk` int(11) NOT NULL
)

Comment: insert into schedule (game_id,game_date,game_time,home_team_id,away_team_id,venue_id,id,is_active,game_pk) values

Comment: ('atlmlb-nynmlb-1', '2017-04-03 00:00:00', '2017-04-03 17:10:00', 'd879c5a4-bed1-11e6-b63c-1188955be771', 'd92a02e1-bed1-11e6-b63c-1188955be771', '23fe64a2-b92d-11e6-9bee-a1341b18de4a', 'e425227c-bed1-11e6-b63c-1188955be771', '1', '490098')

('chnmlb-slnmlb-1', '2017-04-02 00:00:00', '2017-04-03 00:30:00', 'd8d245eb-bed1-11e6-b63c-1188955be771', 'd7ea08bc-bed1-11e6-b63c-1188955be771', '23fabb21-b92d-11e6-9bee-a1341b18de4a', 'e422d886-bed1-11e6-b63c-1188955be771', '1', '490099')

Add some duplicate data with the same game_pk and different primary (id).

Comment: In the stored procedure, where do you control the value of the `keep_entry` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have Changed My Stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `remove_schedule_duplicate`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE schedule_id,temp CHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE gamePk INTEGER;
    DECLARE keep_entry TINYINT(1);
    DECLARE scheduleDuplicate CURSOR FOR SELECT game_pk,id FROM schedule where game_pk in (SELECT game_pk FROM schedule where is_active = 1 group by game_pk,home_team_id,away_team_id,venue_id having count(game_pk) > 1) and is_active = 1 order by game_pk;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN scheduleDuplicate;

        get_schedule_duplicate: LOOP

        FETCH scheduleDuplicate INTO gamePk,schedule_id;

        IF finished = 1 THEN
            LEAVE get_schedule_duplicate;
        END IF;

        IF ((temp IS NULL) AND (gamePk IS NOT NULL)) OR ((temp IS NOT NULL) AND (temp <> gamePk)) THEN
            SET temp = gamePk;
            SET keep_entry = 1;
        #ELSE IF temp IS NOT NULL AND temp = gamePk THEN
        ELSE
            SET keep_entry = 0;
        END IF;

        IF keep_entry = 0 THEN
                UPDATE schedule set is_active = 0 where id = schedule_id;
        END IF;

        END LOOP get_schedule_duplicate;

    CLOSE scheduleDuplicate;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```